# Servlet code dispatching to JSP shows error

Tags: java, html, validation, jsp, servlets

I have the following code which validates a Sign up form. I have two methods which validate if "Password" and "Confirm password" are the same and sends an error message if not and also checkEmail() which checks the DB if the email already exists. When I don't include the checkEmail() method the other one works fine (even the error message). But when I include the checkEmail() it gives an error message of NullPointerException. I believe it has to do with the incorporation of the checkEmail() method in my code but I am not sure where to put it. I would be grateful if anyone could help me.

//SERVLET doPost METHOD

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        HttpSession s = request.getSession();
        UserInfo ud = new UserInfo(); 
        ud.createTable();
        UserBean u = new UserBean();
        ServletContext ctx = s.getServletContext();

            u.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
            u.setName(request.getParameter("name"));
            u.setLname(request.getParameter("sname"));
            u.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));
            s.setAttribute("User", u);
            String e = u.getEmail();
            String p1 = u.getPassword();
            String p2 = request.getParameter("password2");

            if(User.confirmPassword(p1, p2) && !User.checkEmail(e)) {

            //Save data to DB
            u = (User)s.getAttribute("User");
            s.invalidate();
            ud.insert(u);
            forwardTo(ctx, request, response, "/Somepage.jsp");

            } else {
                if(User.checkEmail(e)) {
                        request.setAttribute("name",request.getParameter("name"));
                        request.setAttribute("sname",request.getParameter("sname"));
                        request.setAttribute("email",request.getParameter("email"));
                        request.setAttribute("pass", request.getParameter("password"));
                        request.setAttribute("pass2", request.getParameter("password2"));
                        request.setAttribute("errorMessage", "Email already exists!");
                        request.getRequestDispatcher("/SignUp.jsp").forward(request, response);
                }
                if(!User.confirmPassword(p1, p2)) {
                request.setAttribute("name",request.getParameter("name"));
                request.setAttribute("sname",request.getParameter("sname"));
                request.setAttribute("email",request.getParameter("email"));
                request.setAttribute("pass", request.getParameter("password"));
                request.setAttribute("pass2", request.getParameter("password2"));
                request.setAttribute("errorMessage", "Passwords do not match!");
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/SignUp.jsp").forward(request, response);
                    }
                } 
            }
```

//SIGN UP FORM

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>User Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action = "UserServ" method ="POST">
<h5 >Enter the details below to Sign Up</h5><br>
Name: <input type="text" name="name" required placeholder="Firstname" value="${name}"><br>
Surname: <input type="text" name="sname" required placeholder="Surname" value="${sname}"><br>
Email: <input type="text" value="${email}" name="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
Password:
<input type="password" value="${pass}" name="password" placeholder="Password"  required><br>
Confirm password:
<input type="password" name="password2" value="${pass2}" placeholder="Confirm password" required><br>
<div style="color: #FF0000;">${errorMessage}</div><br>
<input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
</form>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

//METHODS

```
public static boolean confirmPassword(String p1, String p2){          
        boolean status = false;  
        if(p1.equals(p2)) {
        status =true;  
        }
        return status;
    }


    public static boolean checkEmail(String email) {
        boolean check = false;
         PreparedStatement pst = null;  
            ResultSet rs = null;  
            try(Connection conn= ConnectionConfiguration.getConnection()){
                pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?;");  
                pst.setString(1, email);  

                check = rs.next();  
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return check;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ResultSet is never calculated as the prepared statement is never executed. This results in the NPE while executing `rs.next()`.

Add sth like this after setting the email:

```
rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

This will execute the prepared statement with the given parameters and return the ResultSet you're looking for.

BTW:

Please consider using `rs.isBeforeFirst()` instead of `rs.next()` for checking if there is any result. In your case it will work, because you're not reading any row, but if, you'll need to reset the cursor as `rs.next()` moves the cursor to the next row if present.

Comment: deleted comment

Comment: Yes that was the problem but I also have another question. If both the passwords are not equal and the email exists how can I make both errors appear at the same time. Because with the current implementation that I have written above it only shows me the Email error.

Comment: I mean appart from adding another div because I have added it with another ${errorMsg }but it only generates the email error still and says in the console it gives the following error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed

Comment: As this answer solves your problem, rewading will be appreciated ;)

Comment: You'll need to save the result of User.checkEmail(email) and User.confirmPassword(p1, p2) both in separate variables.  After that set the errorMessage depending on both resuts. Finally assign all input independent attributes to the request.

Comment: yes, that's what I did but it showed the error: IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed. I read somewhere I should use Filters but I do not understand how I can implement them

Comment: Sure Stephanie, this is because this line: request.getRequestDispatcher("/SignUp.jsp").forward(request, response);    All your code needs to be placed before. In other words, this line needs to be the last one. You'll need to refactor the else block.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182527/discussion-between-ibexit-and-stephanie).